# The right cast sequence from int** to int* volatile* in C++

Tags: c++, casting, volatile

I wanna cast `T**` to `T * volatile *` using C++ style cast. 
Is this right?

```
using namespace std;
int** p = nullptr;
auto cast_ptr = static_cast<
                    add_pointer_t<
                        add_volatile_t<
                            remove_pointer_t<decltype(p)>>>>(p);
```

Comment: Hmm, no `#include` directives, but `using namespace std;`. Cargo cult programming?

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler:

```
auto casted_ptr = static_cast<int * volatile *>(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is right.
Here is a simple method to verify. This should work with g++.

```
#include <typeinfo>

cout << typeid(p).name() << endl;
```

And execute it like this:

```
$ ./a.out | c++filt -t
```

You will get the follow output:

```
int* volatile*
```